# Magento create checkbox attribute for products programmatically

Tags: magento

How can I create an product attribute? It should be a checkbox.

Comment: Show us your code and explain a bit more where an what you want to do and what did not work in your code.

Comment: $installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'global_feed_title', 
        array(
                'label'  => 'Use default settings',
                'type'  => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'input'  => 'boolean',
                'global' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order'=> 1100,
                'is_user_defined' => false,
                'visible' => false,
                'searchable'=> false,
                'comparable'=> false,
                'filterable'=> false

        ));

Comment: @KNKM Please edit your question to add and properly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Actually there is no any 'input' as checkbox. So what i did was, i created a select dropdown and by code i used it as a checkbox by changing necessary things.

Thank you so much for helping.